# how to combine query() and limit() methods in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, limit

Is it possible to do something like this in codeigniter:

```
publi function getcat($category_id)
{
    $query = "(SELECT cat.id, cat.title ";
    $query = $query . "FROM bf_categories cat ";
    $query = $query . "WHERE cat.id=" . $category_id;
    $this->db->limit(2, 4);
    $records = $this->db->query($query);
    return $records->result();
}
```

I've simplified the query just for demo purposes... but it's actually quite complex, which is why I've decided to use the `query()` method.

But the limit clause is not being included in the query... I've verified by enabling the codeigniter profiler in my controller and I can see that the query is run with out any limit clause.

Can you tell me how I can accomplish this using the `query()` method?

**Edit 1**

I've modified my model to look like this:

```
public function get_categories_and_products($limit=5, $offset=0, $category_id=null)
{
    print "<BR>the function got the following offeset: $offset and limit: $limit";
    $query = "(SELECT cat.category_id, cat.title, cat.image_thumb, cat.deleted, cat.display_weight ";
            $query = $query."FROM bf_categories cat ";
            $query = $query."WHERE cat.parent_id=".$category_id;
    $query = $query." AND cat.category_id <>".$category_id;
    $query = $query.") UNION (";
    $query = $query."SELECT p.product_id, p.name, p.image_thumb, p.deleted , p.display_weight";
    $query = $query." FROM bf_product p ";
    $query = $query."Inner join bf_product_category cp ";
    $query = $query."on p.product_id=cp.product_id ";
    $query = $query."Where cp.category_id=".$category_id.") ?";

            $records = $this->db->query($query,array($this->db->limit(2, 4)));
            return $records->result();
     }
```

I've hardcoded the limit values for now... but ultimately, i'll be using the values that get passed into the method.  Unfortunately, this code still does not work. 
According to the profiler, here's what's being executed:

```
(SELECT cat.category_id, cat.title, cat.image_thumb, cat.deleted, cat.display_weight FROM bf_categories cat WHERE cat.parent_id=3 AND cat.category_id <>3) UNION (SELECT p.product_id, p.name, p.image_thumb, p.deleted , p.display_weight FROM bf_product p Inner join bf_product_category cp on p.product_id=cp.product_id Where cp.category_id=3)

SELECT * FROM (`bf_categories`) WHERE `category_id` = '3' LIMIT 4, 2
```

So it's creating two separate select statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, I'm doing everything manually.

```
public function get_categories_and_products($limit=10, $offset=0, $category_id=null)
{
    $query = "(SELECT cat.category_id, cat.title, cat.image_thumb, cat.deleted, cat.display_weight ";
    $query = $query."FROM bf_categories cat ";
    $query = $query."WHERE cat.parent_id=".$category_id;
    $query = $query." AND cat.category_id <>".$category_id;
    $query = $query.") UNION (";
    $query = $query."SELECT p.product_id, p.name, p.image_thumb, p.deleted , p.display_weight";
    $query = $query." FROM bf_product p ";
    $query = $query."Inner join bf_product_category cp ";
    $query = $query."on p.product_id=cp.product_id ";
    $query = $query."Where cp.category_id=".$category_id.") limit ".$offset.','.$limit;
    $catsandprods= $this->db->query($query);
    return $catsandprods->result();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried this way, multiple join with start and limit. you remove join as per choice.

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_requestservice as r');
    $this->db->join('tbl_service as s','s.service_id=r.service_id');
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    print_r($query->result());
    return $query->result();
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how a query looks like in CI:

```
$this->db->select("id, title");
$this->db->where("id", $category_id);
$this->db->from("bf_categories");
$this->db->limit($limit);
$query = $this->db->get();

if($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
   foreach($query->result() as $row)
   {
      echo $row->title;
   }
}
```

If you include the full query, it would be easier to solve the problem or show you a better and more efficient approach.

Comment: this is resource intensive you are not applying limit

Answer (score 2):

[http://code-igniter.ru/user_guide/database/active_record.html](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

```
$this->db->start_cache();
$this->db->select('field1');
$this->db->stop_cache();
$this->db->get('tablename');
```

SELECT `field1` FROM (`tablename`)

```
$this->db->select('field2');
$this->db->limit(10);
$this->db->get('tablename');
```

// SELECT `field1`, `field2` FROM (`tablename`) limit 10

```
$this->db->flush_cache();
$this->db->select('field2');
$this->db->get('tablename');
```

// SELECT `field2` FROM (`tablename`)

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
$query = "(SELECT cat.id, cat.title ";
$query = $query."FROM bf_categories cat ";
$query = $query."WHERE cat.id=".$category_id." ?";

$this->db->query($query,array($this->db->limit(2, 4)));
```

or

```
 $this->db->select('id,title')->from('bf_categories ')->where('id', $id)->limit(2, 4);
```

[link to doc](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)

Comment: The only thing I would add to this is that the reason the OP's example doesn't work the way it was intended was that it was trying to improperly combine the query() function which typically is meant to execute sql queries in the database's native language whereas the limit() function is part of the CodeIgniter Active Record library which is a database agnostic querying structure.

Comment: actually he is not trying to add limit ,he is not at all adding it ,he is simply using  `$this->db->limit(2, 4);` thinking that might automatically add limit

Comment: Arun, I've just tried updating my code to match your example and it's not working.  Please check out Edit 1 in my post.  Thanks!

Comment: i think yo u missed out the **?** symbol

Comment: arun, I imagine the ? comes after a closing ")" ?  you don't have that in your example but... I think it'll generate a syntax error.  I'm not in the office but when i get back I will give it a try

Comment: Arun, I've added the ? symbol but that doesn't make a difference.  The limit clause is still not kicking in and I still have the two separate sql queries being executed.

Comment: dot just see how the actual query is build by echoing

Comment: @dot... why don't you simply add your LIMIT clause to the SQL... you've manually written the rest of the SQL line so what's a few more characters?

Comment: Kenneth, i think i'm heading in that direction.  this started out as a "how do i do this in ci" exercise, but it seems that given the complex nature of the query itself, it's best just to do it all manually.

Comment: Arun, the profiler shows you all queries. I don't think I understand what you mean...